# Using Webpack's Coffee-Loader without explicitly stating ".coffee" file extension

Tags: build, webpack, coffeescript

## preface

I am currently switching our build process over from Browserify to Webpack.  As the project uses a great deal of coffee-script, I have many import statements such as:

```
require('./coffee-file-without-extension') # note the lack of .coffee
require('./legacy-js-file-without-extension') # note the lack of .js
```

---

## problem

Browserify handles the absence of the file extension just fine.  Webpack seems to have issue per this error:

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './wptest-req' in '/Users/jusopi/Dev/Workspaces/nx/nx-ui/src'

I setup a super simple test project for this where I have the following files:

**wptest.coffee**

```
require('./wptest-req')
```

**wptest-req.coffee**

```
module.exports = {}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {

  entry: {
    main: './src/wptest.coffee'
  },

  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'common' // Specify the common bundle's name.
   })
  ],

  module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.coffee$/,
            use: [
                {
                    loader: 'coffee-loader',
                    options: { sourceMap: true }
                }
            ]   
        }
    ]
  }
};
```

---

## end-goal

I am *hoping* I do not have to go over **every** file in our application and append `.coffee` to all require statements for coffee files if at all possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While this solution is not specific to coffee-loader, it did resolve my issue.  I needed to add a `resolve` object to my configuration:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {

    entry: {
        main: './src/main.coffee'
        // other: './src/index2.js'
    },

    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    },

    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
          name: 'common' // Specify the common bundle's name.
        })
    ],

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.coffee$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'coffee-loader',
                        options: { sourceMap: true }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },

    resolve: {
        extensions: [ '.coffee', '.js' ]
    }
};
```

src - https://github.com/webpack-contrib/coffee-loader/issues/36